# Atom not recognising CSS grid commands "justify-items" and "justify-self". Why?

Tags: css, justify, css-grid

For some weird reason, atom is not recognising the `justify-items` and `justify-self` commands used in css grids. Does anyone know why that is, and if there is a fix for it?

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [page-start] 1fr [content-start] 80vw [content-end] 1fr [page-end];
  grid-template-rows:
    [header] 5vh [home] 50vh [about] 5em [empty-start-one] 50vh
    [empty-end-one] 5em [services] 50vh [portfolio] 50vh [contact] 5em
    [empty-start-two] 30vh [footer] 10vh [footer-end];
}
```

[image]

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box header">
</div>
```

Comment: Please post enough code in your question to reproduce the problem. Also, which browsers are you targeting?

Comment: The commands are not even recognised and blurred out - not having any impact on anything. Currently targeting just chrome.

Comment: I have just updated the question with relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've posted in the question doesn't look right.

`justify-items` applies to the grid container. It aligns the child elements of the container. Essentially, it establishes the default `justify-self` value for all items.

You have `justify-items` applied to the grid item (`.header`).

Therefore, unless the item is also a grid container, `justify-items` will have no effect.

`justify-self` applies to grid items. It enables individual items to override the value of `justify-items` set by the container.

[According to the grid spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#propdef-justify-self), `justify-self: start` is a valid rule when applied to a grid item.

Answer (score 2):

Is this a Less file?

This highlighting is controlled by the language plugin for the current file’s recognized language. The current versions of the `language-css` and `language-postcss` support these properties, so they should provide the correct hooks for your syntax highlighting theme to color them correctly. However, I’ve noticed the `language-less` package does not support them.

You can normally see which language the current file is set to in the toolbar on the bottom of the screen. It is displayed on the bottom right, beside the file’s character encoding.